# Printing 10 numbers in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have just began to learn Haskell.
I am experienced with C, C++, Java and PHP.
Still I cant figure out how do I print numbers from 0 to 10 in Haskell whithout having `putStrLn` on different lines.

In Java, we would do like this :

```
for(int i=0; i<=10; i++)
    System.out.println(i);
```

Howver, Haskell doesn't seem to support this.
How can I produce the same result ?

Comment: `main = mapM_ print [0..10]`  You should read a haskell tutorial, http://learnyouahaskell.com is pretty good for the basics

Comment: But I think that is specifically for printing numbers. I want some loop like structure/s

Comment: `mapM_` *is* the "loop-like" structure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess your question really boils down to: How do I loop in Haskell?

And the answer to this is to recurse. And because it's Haskell, for the most common kinds of recursions you already have idioms. You can use `ghci` for the following examples.

Here are 2 common loop translation examples:

In C:

```
int a[10];

for (i=0; i<10; i++)
    a[i] = i*i;
```

and in Haskell:

```
a = map (\i -> i*i) [1..10]
```

which reads, apply a function that takes an number and returns the number multiplied with itself, to a list of 10 numbers. This technique is called a **`map`**.

or

```
a = [ i*i | i <- [1..10] ]
```

which is very similar to the set-builder notation. This technique is called **List comprehension**.

Their output:

```
[1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81,100]
```

Here's another one:
C:

```
int a = 1;

for (i=1; i<10; i++)
    a = a *i;
```

Haskell:

```
foldl (\currentValue i -> currentValue * i) 1 [1..10]
```

Output:

```
3628800
```

And this one above is called **folding**.

Now, what you're doing is printing to a screen. So you would expect to do the following:

```
map (\i -> putStrLn (show i)) [1..10]
```

which reads, apply a function that prints the "show" value of a number onto the list of numbers from 1 to 10.
But since this is just a expression, the output of that line is actually a list of printing computations:

```
[ IO(), IO (), IO() ]
```

This is not an easy type to display, so ghci just returns an error to you.

For your purposes, printing 10 values, you need to do a monadic map:

```
mapM (\i -> putStrLn (show i)) [1..10]
```

or better yet,

```
mapM_ (\i -> putStrLn (show i)) [1..10]
```

Why, and how this happens is more of a foray into `IO` and monads.

Answer (score 5):

Haskell doesn't have `for` loops like some other languages, but it does have `for each` loops:

So, we just do `print` for each number 0 to 10:

```
import Control.Monad       -- forM_ is not part of the syntax itself, but defined as a function

main :: IO ()              -- main does IO
main = do
  forM_ [0..10] $ \n ->    -- for each number 0 to 10
    print n                -- print the number
```

Or shorter:

```
import Control.Monad

main :: IO ()
main = forM_ [0..10] print
```

Comment: And to relate to the comments: `forM_ lst fn = mapM_ fn lst`

Comment: What does thet $ and \n mean?

Comment: @Aditya `$` is just function application. `\n` is just a lambda (`\n -> print n` is a function that takes a Number and prints it) taking one argument which will be bound to the name `n`. But really, you should just read a haskell tutorial! If you only know C++/Java/C/..., Haskell is not a language where you just need to learn a new syntax. It's very different from other languages, not only in syntax, but also in the way of thinking.

Comment: Try [Learn You A Haskell For Great Good](http://learnyouahaskell.com) if you're looking for a good beginner's tutorial.

Comment: "Haskell doesn't have `for` loops like some other languages" Haskell has recursion, which is at least as expressive.